# std::format precision must be a constexpr?

Tags: c++, c++20

I have a function, which is used to get the fixed digit's string of input double.

the function is:

```
std::string to_fixed_string(double s, size_t n) {
  char buff[64];
  snprintf(buff, sizeof(buff), ("%." + std::to_string(n) + "f").c_str(), s); 
  return buff;
}
```

recently i am using std::format, the most important reason is std::format is faster than snprintf.

but i found the constexpr limit make this function not work.

is there any more effiective method to implement this function?

example is:

```
func(1.123123131, 3) -> "1.123"
func(1.123123131, 5) -> "1.12312"
```

Comment: you say you are using `std::format` rather than `snprintf` but the code you posted is using `snprintf` not `format`. "but i found the constexpr limit make this function not work." what does that mean? Please post a [mcve] of the code with `std::format` that is "not work"

Comment: why on earth do you convert the std::string to `char*` then back to `std::string`??

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai I bet they tried the same approach (generating the format string at runtime), which `std::format` doesn't allow by default.

Comment: Be careful with statements like _"the most important reason is std::format is faster than snprintf"._ I highly doubt that it's true and you should verify this before opting to use something because of these reasons. These two statements are very different, and I don't see any reason why `snprintf` should be slower, but rather the opposite! However, `std::format` is generally safer as it's less error-prone, but it also returns a `std::string` that might be heap allocated. In your case, it might be faster because you're converting the string to char* and then back to string again, which is slow.

Comment: @phuclv i thought there is no performace loss, i think i was wrong as Ted points out.

Comment: @TedKleinBergman thanks, i just do some tiny test, and the simple timer tolds me std::format is faster than snprintf, and thanks again for letting me know the heap allocated problem, i will dive into it.

Comment: you do not need to allocate any additional memory. If the string is known to contain a single floating point number then all you need to do is find the position of the `.` then adjust the strings size accordingly. Not sure if doing this manually will be any faster than `snprintf` or `format`, I'd expect it to be similar and not much slower. If yuo care about performance you need to implement both and measure. There is no other way

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai oh, i can find the ., than resize or substr. that's clean, i believe it's fast

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai i will test, yes, optimize the latency is more complex than what i imaged before, much things need to learn. :(

Comment: obviously there'll be some performance loss, because when constructing the return value you'll need to allocate memory, find the zero terminator and copy the string into the result `std::string`. Similarly `snprintf` also has to find the null terminator, which is completely unnecessary with `std::string`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`std::format("{:.{}f}", value, precision)`, note `{}` instead of the precision number.

`printf` has an equivalent feature, you can put `*` instead of the number (but unlike `format` the precision argument goes before the value argument, not after). If you continue to use `printf` for some reason, you should be doing this instead of generating the format string.

Comment: thanks, i do generate the format string at runtime

Comment: @nick Yep, and you normally shouldn't be doing that.